# Add a column with value generatet with GENERATESERIES

Tags: powerbi

I am looking for a simple way to insert the values calculated with the GENERATESERIES function into a column in an existing table. GENERATESERIES creates a new table, but I want to insert the values into an existing table.
I just can't find a simple solution.

Comment: Probably easier in SQL:

INSERT INTO "your.table" ("pick.a.column.")
SELECT * FROM GENERATESERIES("strating.value", "ending.value",  "constant.step.interger");

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in power query. Click on Home-> Transform Data. Now Power Query opens.
Click on Add Column ->Index Column.

```
= Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type)
```

Your added Column is on the right and starts with 0, if you like 1 more, change zero :-)

You can drag your new column as first column to the left. Rest to do is save and close power query